# Image Segmentation based on Pixel Density

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I need some help developing some code that segments a binary image into components of a certain pixel density. I've been doing some research in OpenCV algorithms, but before developing my own algorithm to do this, I wanted to ask around to make sure it hasn't been made already.

For instance, in this picture, I have code that imports it as a binary image. However, is there a way to segment objects in the objects from the lines? I would need to segment nodes (corners) and objects (the circle in this case). However, the object does not necessarily have to be a shape.

The solution I thought was to use pixel density. Most of the picture will made up of lines, and the objects have a greater pixel density than that of the line. Is there a way to segment it out?

Below is a working example of the task.

**Original Picture:**

[image: Original Picture]

**Resulting Images after Segmentation of Nodes** (intersection of multiple lines) and Components (Electronic components like the Resistor or the Voltage Source in the picture)

[image: Node 1]

[image: Voltage Source]

[image: Node 2]

[image: Resistor]

[image: Node 3]

[image: Node 4]

Comment: why dont you use the rectangle as a basis? i mean, detect it, and search for features moving onto it. you just need a pre-assumption of all circuits (and subcircuits) are drawn rectangular. Even if the circuit is complicated, you can solve by detecting all rectangles and searching through them.

Comment: rectangle detection = skaletonize + line detection + find corners

Comment: I guess I could do that, I'll try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [integral image](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=integral#integral) to quickly compute the density of black pixels in a rectangular region. Detection of regions with high density can then be performed with a moving window in varying scales. This would be very similar to how face detection works but using only one super-simple feature.

It might be beneficial to make all edges narrow with something like [skeletonizing](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/) before computing the integral image to make the result insensitive to wide lines.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the moving window to detect only half of the voltage source? I feel like it will move around the image and detect a high pixel density in just the plus sign and consider it as an entire component. How can I avoid this?

Comment: When you have overlapping detected regions in different scales, the larger scales can be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has some [functionality for finding contours](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) that is able to put the contours in a hierarchy. It might be what you are looking for. If not, please add some more information about your expected output!

Comment: I do not think that this is what I am looking for. Please see my question again. I edited it and put a much better example of what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to detect the lines and the circle in your image, right?

If it is the case, have a look at the [Hough line transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) and [Hough circle transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html).

Comment: I do not only want to detect between lines and circles. I would like to break up the image into sub-images of the corners and the circle in one segmentation algorithm. I'll fix up the question to describe what I want better.

Comment: But if you detect the circle, then you can make a sub-image out of it, can't you? Same for the corners...